# Can I block porn sites using OPEN DNS service or Windows-10 built in tools?

Tags: windows-10

I bumped into this site after weeks and even years of frustration as no one seems to know. Paid $10 a year for 4 years for OpenDNS service and thought it was doing what they claimed to do all along but now I realize it never worked. Their tech rep spent about 2 hrs with me on the phone and now seems to have given up and doesn't respond to my emails anymore.

I have a powerful desktop and a laptop and two boys under 15 growing up in our home. 
**Windows 10** on both machines with a **DLINK DIR 632** router.
Dynamic IP setting with **Primary DNS 208.67.222.222 and Secondary DNS 208.67.220.220 per OPen DNS instruction**s. Same settings in Network Connections TCP/IPv4 as well. Open DNS set to highest security level and makes no difference at all. Everything comes thru like an open faucet.
Since Open DNS couldn't help, I thought maybe Windows 10 could help but for some strange reason, I don't see a **Family Safety** icon under *Control Panel>User Accounts*. Spent a lot of time with it and it appears Microsoft is more concerned about getting kids individual emails and sending them their separate ways.

Any HELP would be greatly appreciated. Someone said setting a static IP might work. If so, do I have to do it both on the Router and in my Network Settings.
Or is it that my DLINK router has compatibility issues. I am not looking to block 100% of porn sites - which would be impossible- but at least a good portion of it if I can.

Here is what I got for `nslookup`.

```
nslookup xvideos.com
Server: resolver1.opendns.com  
Address: 208.67.222.222  

Non-authoritative answer:  
Name: xvideos.com  
Addresses:   
 141.0.174.37  
 141.0.174.38  
 141.0.174.40  
 141.0.174.41  
 141.0.174.42  
 141.0.174.43  
 141.0.174.44  
 141.0.174.34  
 141.0.174.35  
 141.0.174.36
```

Comment: Migrating to a forum that is better suited to this question.

Comment: If they're 15 and a little bit tech-savvy, they'll quickly google how to bypass your DNS restrictions by using a proxy-website or changing their DNS server on the local machine to google's `8.8.8.8`, so don't expect your DNS blockade to be effective. In regards to the problem: So although you set your DNS settings in the router to `208.67.222.123` but sites can still be resolved? Restart your router, restart your computer, then give us the output of the CMD command `nslookup xvideos.com` please.

Comment: If you want to block websites that bypass the restrictions, then tick the "Anonymiser" box to block them too.

Comment: Didn't get this. Where is the 'Anonymiser' box.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: In response to Maxmillian after changing DNS to ..123Server:  resolver1-fs.opendns.com
Address:  208.67.222.123

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xvideos.com
Addresses:  146.112.61.106
          146.112.61.106

Answer (score 1):

No technical solution exists to actually, effectively do what you want to do.  If China's government can't effectively censor the internet, having spent untold billions of dollars to do so, and actually owning their country's telecommunications infrastructure, why would you think you'd be able to, as an end-consumer?

Porn is everywhere online anyway, and blocking porn sites doesn't stop that.  They'll still be able to get it on general filesharing sites, through social networking and from their peers, so you're fighting a hopelessly lost cause.

The only way to stop someone from accessing objectionable material online is to prevent them from getting online.  You may as well make your peace with that, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Like locks on a car door, if you put enough hurdles in the way, you can at least keep honest people honest. 95% of the time, you don't need a 100% foolproof solution. Especially considering pornography, where by the time they figure out how to bypass what you can do, they could instead...um...not need to access it anymore.

Comment: @Ben and to you, a 15 year old in search of porn is an example of an honest person you'll keep honest with a trivially-bypassed lock?  Good luck with that.  And just for the record, locks don't keep honest people honest, they keep lazy criminals out, some of the time.

Comment: I could agree to consider a teenager in search of porn a lazy criminal then, if you prefer. I know I would not have been determined enough in my teenage years to research bypass methods, but maybe I was more honest/lazy than  most teenagers. I can't really say.

Comment: Plus, it's good for getting rid of accidental discovery to put the hurdles in place.

Comment: @Ben It's also a lot easier these days. With Google, you can learn how to bypass these content-filtering schemes almost instantaneously, so the threshold for whom they deter is a lot lower. As I alluded to, they don't address the multiple other sources of pornography online, either. If the children are young enough that "accidental discovery" is a problem, content-filtering can be of some use, but the better approach is not letting young children have unsupervised internet/computer access. There's just no getting around that this isn't a technical issue, and thus, can't be solved technically.

Comment: -1 this answer isn't helpful. you're just telling him that he's hopeless. A better answer might have included how much he can block with OpenDNS or Windows 10 and what the limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is : edit your "hosts" file. Goto : C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Copy "hosts" file to other directory. Except directory under C. Add one line to the end of the file. Example : if I want to block google, then I need to add lines as :
127.0.0.1 tonec.com

127.0.0.1 www.google.com

127.0.0.1 google.com

127.0.0.1 https://google.com

Then save it and replace the original hosts file (ie. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) with this modified one.

Answer (score -3):

So here is [something](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/features/how-to-block-any-website-on-your-computer-phone-or-network-588357) that might help. Set some websites that you want to block, disable read/write privileges on this file for their account, and I guess this will do.
I know it's a bad way since you need to enter the websites manually but it's better than nothing.

Comment: It's also bad because it's trivial to workaround.  If the kids have physical access to the computer in question, there's no way to stop them from undoing all that, or booting into a live CD, or whatever else.

Comment: I mentioned the access privileges and I'm not sure if the kids will go that far to boot into a live CD. I know there isn't a solution, as you can always get access to that in some ways, but if they work around this you just made them learn something about computers in the process.

Comment: 1) Physical access is total access.  You put all the software-level access restrictions you want in place, and I can undo them in no time with physical access to the machine.  Anyone can, with very minimal technical knowledge, too.  2) Why do you assume the kids won't go as far as downloading a free piece of software and putting it on a flash drive?  I did.  (And more.) I was that age in the 1990's, when it actually took effort, and more than 15 minutes, too.

Comment: @HopelessN00b You should talk to the FBI, they would probably pay you handsomely to unlock some of their iOS things. To be fair, if a device has the capabilities to lock down the boot drive/partition and the drive itself is fully encrypted, you can make it pretty infeasible to alter the software without replacing some hardware. Most devices aren't really made to be capable of this though.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You'd probably be surprised at how little those exploits typically sell for.  It's a moot point anyway, since I have more morality and sense to work for the government anyhow.